# JPA Change default Flushmode from AUTO to COMMIT

Tags: jpa

I've tried several ways to change the FlushMode to the complete application.
Is this right or is there another way to do it?

I don't want to do this pragmmatically.

This is was what i find as property but it isn't work.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU">
        <properties>
            ...
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <!-- Also tried this: -->

            <property name="org.hibernate.FlushMode" value="commit"/>
            ...
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update:**

I've created the class as described in the link by zxcf, but i can't figure out how to add this construct in my persistence.xml.

```
<property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="test.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
        <property name="flushMode" value="MANUAL"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
<property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>
```

Testing this on a standalone program I can see the changed value of underlying Hibernate Session / EntityManager from `AUTO`  to `COMMIT`

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="JPATest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>  

  <class>com.test.TestEntity</class>  
  <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> 
  <properties> 
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>     
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>      
       <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
       <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.use.second.level.cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="neutrino.jpa.cache"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
      <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
    <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>    
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is how I test it

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf  = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPATest");
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
 Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
 System.out.println("Underlying Hibernate session flushmode #######         "+session.getFlushMode());
 System.out.println("EntityManager flushmode                #######         "+em.getFlushMode());
```

This gives me

```
Underlying Hibernate session flushmode #######         COMMIT
EntityManager flushmode                #######         COMMIT
```

If I omit the property in presistence.xml, I get this

```
Underlying Hibernate session flushmode #######         AUTO
EntityManager flushmode                #######         AUTO
```

Comment: Is this just a capitalization issue with the value?

Comment: Look like that was it ! Please test at your end and don't forget to mark this question as answered :-)

Comment: Please see my update for the configuration I have tested against.

Comment: I don't work with the session. I do em.persist() and my entityManager has the FlushMode AUTO if i use this property in my persistence.xml. I believe that is what zxcf said.

Comment: When you are working with Hibernate, the underlying session is what is doing the actual work. Hibernate provides JPA implementation by providing wrappers over its SessionFactory and Session . You can verify this by reading the source code of org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl. I had used the session just to show that the underlying session has also the flushmode change reflected. Please see the update in my answer where I have used the entity manager as well.

Comment: I believe you but it still not working. I have a dependency hibernate-jpa-2.0-api: 1.0.1.Final. Maybe this is the reason. By the way thanks for your help till now its great.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1 from JBoss 4.2.3.GA supports only the following notation:

```
<property name="flush-mode" value="commit"/>
```