# JpaRepository save flushes all entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using jpatransactionmanager in spring data jpa and provider is Hibernate.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>
```

I have three entities say Aentity, Bentity. A and B has one to one relation. There is a third entity Centity. Persistence of Centity is independent of Aentity and Bentity. However, I have found whenever Centity is saved Aentity and Bentity are flushed automatically to db. I want to control this behaviour and want to ensure that they should be persisted when i call save using their repository.

Other Info:
Aentity has cascase on for B.
Transaction Info for Centity is : Propogation: requires new and isolation=default

I have looked in many forums but could not find hint/solution.

Comment: Hibernate keeps managed entities in a `Session`. The `Session` is synchronised with the database through a process known as flush. When a `Session` is flushed is controlled by a [flushing strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#AUTO) on the `Session`. The default strategy is `AUTO`, which [sometimes flushes the `Session`](https://dzone.com/articles/dark-side-hibernate-auto-flush) before executing a `SELECT` query. The flushing strategy [can be changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778966/jpa-change-default-flushmode-from-auto-to-commit).

Answer (score 0):

May be autocommit is enabled hence entities are flushing to database as soon you are calling save method.
Try using this.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Comment: entities for which save has not been called are also getting saved. That is the concern. I believe jpatransactionmanager works over a persistence context, is there any property where i can tweak this aspect. Using HibernateTransactionManager will not be helpful in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you do some modification in related objects which you do not want to store in database, you should detach them from entityManager like this:

```
    static void applyToEntity(User user, EntityManager entityManager) {

        entityManager.detach(user); //Detach object because temp settings can be    accidentally stored
        entityManager.detach(user.client) //Detach object because of temp settings can be accidentally stored

        user.client.showActivityContacts = true;
        user.allowRoles = true;
 }
```

It will cause these objects will not be saved in cascade because of they will not be managed anymore.