# Set Flush mode from AUTO to COMMIT in hibernate 3.5.6

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I want to set flush mode from default **AUTO** to **COMMIT** in persistence.xml file,
I have tried below properties one by one,

```
        <property name="org.hibernate.FlushMode" value="COMMIT"/> 

        <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>  

        <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="commit"/>   

        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
```

But none of them seems to work.I have check flushmode using below code,

```
Sysout(((Session)entityManager.getDelegate()).getFlushMode().toString());
```

We are using **JPA version : hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final** and **hibernate version : 3.5.6**

here, is the property tag of my persistence.xml file:

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
        <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>

        <!-- EhCache cache for level 2 -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>

        <!-- To support multiple cache manager in the same VM   -->
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="ehcache-test.xml"></property>

        <!--  Enable second level cache -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>

        <!-- <property name="org.hibernate.FlushMode" value="COMMIT"/> -->

        <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>   
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/> -->

        <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property> -->

        <!--  Enable query cache -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/> 

        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>

        <!-- Showing queries generated by Hibernate                            
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>    
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />--> 

    <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory" value="java:CacheManager"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity" value="mvcc-entity"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query" value="local-query"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="ScoringJPA"/>--> 

    </properties>
```

Comment: @Gimby Yes, it is hibernate 3.5.6.Also updated the description.

Comment: According to [this answer[(http://stackoverflow.com/a/24782092/424903) the `<property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>` test should have been the winner. Please post the persistence.xml. Mask out any sensitive information of course.

Comment: @Gimby In provided link,Please read the nik the lion's last comment.As mention in comment,he also faced the same issue as mine due to jpa version.

Comment: Its a hibernate thing, the JPA version is unrelated. Notice the usage of the word "maybe" in that comment - maybe equals I'm just guessing.

Comment: @Gimby Added snippet of my persistence.xml file.